# how to get list value and count in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist, stop-words

i am trying to count every word in a list.so that i can remove the words which have greater count value.but the output which i am getting is not correct.
suppose if i have these lines in my file "it was the best of times it was the worst of times .it was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness".what my code is doing it prints (was,4) and again somewhere (was,3) and so on.every time the word appears it print the word but with different count value.i need one count of each word.

```
for file in files:  
    print(file)
    f=open(file, 'r')
    content = f.read() 
    wordlist = content.split()
    #print(wordlist)
    wordfreq = [wordlist.count(w) for w in wordlist] # a list comprehension
    print("List\n" + str(wordlist) + "\n")
    print("Frequencies\n" + str(wordfreq) + "\n")
    test = [i for i in wordfreq if i > 100]
    print("result\n"+str(list(zip(test,wordlist))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without Counter:

```
new = s.split(' ')
m=list()
for i in new:
 m.append((i , new.count(i)))
for i in set(m):
    print i
del m[:] # deleting list for using it again
```

output:

```
('best', 1)  
('was', 4)   
('times', 2)  
('it', 3)  
('worst', 1)  
('.it', 1)  
('wisdom', 1)  
('foolishness', 1)  
('the', 4)     
('of', 4) 
('age', 2)

another test : 
 s = 'was was it was hello it was'
output :  
('hello', 1)  
('was', 4)  
('it', 2)
```

if you saved your datas to a file use this :

```
s=""

with open('your-file-name', 'r') as r:
 s+=r.read().replace('\n', '') #reading multi lines

new = s.split(' ')
m=list()
for i in new:
 m.append((i , new.count(i)))
for i in set(m):
    print i
del m[:] # deleting list for using it ag
```

Comment: @user3778289 if you don't want use ( Couner ) module you can simply use this code

Comment: thank you this is pretty good.but still it is giving me the word multiple times.like (was,4),(times,4),again (was,4)

Comment: @user3778289 but in my output (was=4) repeat one (Set) should remove duplicated please copy and paste my code and test again

Comment: it is giving me duplicate output.like i have a large input file.this sentence was just an example

Comment: maybe since i used (m.append()) it's get you duplicated because in each time you test your program datas get append in (m) you should empty list and try again

Comment: the output is like this (it,3) (was,4),(it,3),(was,4) (the,4),(it,3),(was,4),(the,4) (best,1) and so on

Comment: (del m[:]) in end of code should solve problem in my result dosn't exist any duplicated !

Comment: this is giving me a new list every times now.but not the whole list in running the program once

Comment: can you please explain me clearly i don't understand you is there any duplicated value now?

Comment: ('mass', 1)('to', 23)('not', 4)('found', 1)('almost', 1)('main', 1)('membership', 2)('three', 1)('agreed', 1).first time when i am running this is the output and then again when i run my code the output is different

Comment: try to run your code on a large file.you will see the result there

Comment: no different output ! witch is different in your outputs ??

Comment: for file in files:  
    print(file)
    f=open(file, 'r')
    content = f.read() 
    new = content.split(' ')
    m=list()
for i in new:
 m.append((i , new.count(i)))
for i in set(m):
    print (i)
del m[:]

Comment: i dont know what is the issue.but every time when i run the code it gives me different result.first time different words and there count and again different values and their count.but it is giving me the result for those words whose count is less then 10

Comment: ok you have a file and want to cont words in it , i editing my code now and you use it again i checked it no problem

Comment: i edited (r.readline() to s+=r.read().replace('\n', '') copy paste code your problem must get completely solve

Comment: tell me one thing these 2 for loops are nested loops??

Comment: i think a am making some mistake.when i put for loop inside first for loop it print the words multiple time and when i take it out it print just few words and their count..thank you so much for your help i will check it again i am doing something wrong i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) like so:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> s = "it was the best of times it was the worst of times .it was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness"
>>>
>>> d = Counter(s.split())
>>> for k,v in d.items():
...     print '{} -> {}'.format(k,v)
...
of -> 4
age -> 2
it -> 3
foolishness -> 1
times -> 2
worst -> 1
.it -> 1
the -> 4
wisdom -> 1
was -> 4
best -> 1
>>>
```

In case you don't want to use `collections.Counter` you can use a dictionary like so:

```
>>> s = "it was the best of times it was the worst of times .it was the age of wisdom it was the age of foolishness"
>>> d = {}
>>> for word in s.split():
...     try:
...         d[word] += 1
...     except KeyError:
...         d[word] = 1
...
>>> d
{'of': 4, 'age': 2, 'it': 3, 'foolishness': 1, 'times': 2, 'worst': 1, '.it': 1, 'the': 4, 'wisdom': 1, 'was': 4, 'best': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools

for file in files:

    data = itertools.chain.from_iterable([i.strip('\n').split() for i in open(file)])

    the_counts = Counter(data)

    print("wordlist: {}".format(data))
    print("frequencies: {}".format(dict(the_count))
    test = [(a, b) for a, b in the_count.items() if b > 100]
```

Comment: this is giving me an error.test = [(a, b) for a, b in dict(the_count).items() if b > 10]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3778289 Try again and let me know what happens.

Comment: test = [(a, b) for a, b in the_count.items() if b > 10]
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
error is still there

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

for file in files:
    words = open(file).read().split()
    frequencies = Counter(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series(txt.split()).value_counts().reset_index().rename(columns={0:"counts","index":"word"})
a[a.counts<100]
```